# Binance api for PHP function sell() not working

Tags: api, binance

I am using the PHP Binance API from https://php-download.com
I can see my fund:

```
require 'BinanceClass.php';
 $api = new Binance("$k","$s");  // key and secret key
 $balances = $api->balances();
```

But I cannot make an order to Sell:

```
 $quantity=0.076;
 $price = 224.91;
 $order = $api->sell("ETHUSDT", $quantity, $price);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question to save time to others.

Add a var_dump to see api response . If you are getting "Too many parameters; expected '6' and received '9'" then you have an old BinanceClass.
Here how to fix it https://github.com/baitercel/binance-api-php/issues/1